# AS3: htmlText with multiple font size tags?

Tags: actionscript-3, size, textfield, htmltext

I have a textfield that gets text from xml. I added a function for changing font size for a selected text and it works fine until I load the text again. Then it just ignores all other sizes but the first one.

This is the html text for the tekst:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="PresentationOnline_text" SIZE="63" COLOR="#FF9999" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">a<FONT SIZE="33">b</FONT></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

And I just set txtText.htmlText to that. Is it not possible to have several font sizes in one textfield?

When I change the size I do this:

```
textFormat = txtText.getTextFormat(start, end);
textFormat.size = Number(textFormat.size) - 1;
txtText.setTextFormat(textFormat, start, end);
```

Anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

**Edit**:

Works when I do it in this order:

```
txtText.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
txtText.setTextFormat(textFormat);
txtText.htmlText = text;
```

But I know I did it the other way around for some good reason I can't remeber..

Answer (score 1):

> I added a function for changing font size for a selected text and it works fine until I load the text again.

`setTextFormat()` affects the format of the text that is already there. Any text inserted after `setTextFormat()` has beed applied, either manually, or by using `replaceSelectedText()`, will be formatted with the default text format of the textfield.

To set the default text format of the textfield, you must use `defaultTextFormat` property, which is read/write.

Does this info help?

Comment: It's more or less what I do. The issue was the order of it. I need to set the htmlText before if I don't have any formating because I embed my font, and after if I have formating. I think a variation of my edit works as it should, but I need more testing.